# How to see history of modifications for a file from the diverged commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to merge branches `U` into branch `L`. Suppose I have a conflict for the file `A.txt`. I want to take all changes from the remote and add manually all changes made locally. I understand that git applies 3-way-merge with one base commit. So I essentially need a list of all modifications (history) since the base. How can I get it? And is my logic correct?

#### Work in progress

I've run `git merge-base L U` and identified the common base `14b394adb`. I know I can get all history for a file using `git log --follow A.txt`. So I applied this:

```
git log 14b394adba..cb5c3b80fe --follow A.txt
```

which produced the list of commits. Now I need to get diff.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but don't you have a "diff" that show both version in the file itself when a conflict occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note in your own answer, adding `-p` to your `git log --follow` will show you each diff for each commit that `git log --follow` shows.

Be aware that `--follow` looks for renames one commit at a time; but `git merge` *doesn't*.<sup>1</sup>  For instance, suppose you have:

```
          L1--L2--...--Ln   <-- L (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--o   <-- U
```

Here all the *L<sub>i</sub>* commits along the top row, past the merge base *B*, are (only) on the `L` branch (other commits in the diagram are on `U` or on both).  Running:

```
git log --follow B..L -- A.txt
```

will compare commit *L<sub>n-1</sub>* against commit *L<sub>n</sub>*, checking to see if `A.txt` is the result of a rename during this diff.  If so, it will pick a new name to look for; in either case, it now compares *L<sub>n-2</sub>* vs *L<sub>n-1</sub>*.  This repeats until it compares *L<sub>1</sub>* vs *L<sub>2</sub>*, and finally compares *B* vs *L<sub>1</sub>*.

Now suppose, for instance, that there is some moderately large change towards the end between `intermediate.txt` and `A.txt` that causes `git log --follow` to start looking at `intermediate.txt` early on, and then another moderately large change towards the beginning of the chain—or a series of such changes—that makes Git decide that `intermediate.txt` is a result of renaming `original.txt`.

On the other hand, `git merge` is merely running:

```
git diff --find-renames B Ln
```

Here, because there were a lot of fairly big changes, `original.txt` is very different from `A.txt`, and Git does *not* choose it as the "same file" in commits *B* and *L<sub>n</sub>*.  The merge will not see these two as the "same file" and `original.txt` is *not* going to be the base version for the merge's *L* side.  (In this case `A.txt` is *most likely* seen as a new file, rather than a modified file, but there are rarer cases where that's not true.)

Hence, if you are doing this specifically with the intent of comparing the merge base version of whatever Git thinks *became* `A.txt` to the tip L-side version of `A.txt`, you just want one:

```
git diff --find-renames B L -- A.txt
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I would argue that it *should*, or at the least, should have a flag (perhaps `--follow`!) that does this.  But it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very elaborate answer. Is it possible to see diff by commit? Also I'd appreciate if you looked [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47555137/2545680)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "diff by commit" here.

Comment: `git diff` shows the difference between versions as it is now, it doesn't show all differences by commit, e.g. `commit 1 - change this, commit 2 - changed this`

Comment: Ah: see the very first paragraph about adding `-p` to your `git log --follow`.

Comment: great, appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the way to go is:

1) Find common base:

```
base=$(git merge-base L U)
```

2) Get the diff or list of commits from the current branch HEAD to the base commit:

```
git log base..L --full-diff -p A.txt
git log base..L --follow A.txt
```

Also if using IDE by JetBrains it's possible to see it like this:

[image]