# How to specify one or several parents for a commit

Tags: git

I've done a merge and the new merge commit has been created. Then I **soft reset** the branch one commit back to preserve all files with resolutions, reverted one resolution and now I want to create merge commit again using all those files. I have two parent's hashes from the original merge commit and want to somehow specify these parents when creating a new commit to emulate merge commit. Is it possible?

Comment: Reset the branch one back means a hard reset? Which implies you basicilly removed the merge-commit? Is this the right understanding? if not, maybe you visualize it. This is actually always a good idea with git problems.

Comment: You can explicitly merge both the original parents using their hashes, yes, but it's not clear from the question that this is actually what you want.

Comment: @ckruczek, it was a soft reset so that I keep all the files with resolutions. Now I want to commit all resolutions but to emulate merge commit I need to specify two parents.

Comment: @Useless, I don't want to merge anymore. After soft reset I have all the files I need already staged. I made slight changes and now want to emulate merge commit so I need to specify two parents.

Comment: A two-parent commit is created when merging two different heads. I don't see the usecase for emulating it?

Comment: @ckruczek, I don't want to go resolving conflicts from beginning. I already have all resolutions staged after reset.

Comment: Ok so you basically amended the commit before the merge commit and recommited this commit? What you actually have done is to rewrite the history and merge is gone anyway. Even if you would emulate the merge commit you would fall in merge-resultion again, Thats how git works.

Comment: @ckruczek, thanks, but I know what I'm doing. My question is explicitly how to specify two parents for a commit

Comment: With `git merge`. You probably want `git merge -s ours --no-commit <other parent>` (assuming one of the parents is still the parent of your current HEAD).

Comment: Ok let me put it in other words. Without doing a merge you can't. You can't influence the parents for commits without doing a merge. Btw, even if you know what you are doing, for me it looks like you are trying to solve a symptome instead of solving the real problem. And again: You are rewriting the history, and furthermore you try to change the tree structure with 'hack'. I would say you will mess up the repo in future.

Comment: You might be able to fake something with `git update-ref MERGE_HEAD`, but it'd require some experimentation, and I really don't see any benefit.

Comment: @Useless, okay, thanks, I'll explore `git update-ref`. So as I understand there's no way to specify parents for a commit when creating a commit. It's possible though with low level commands, for example, `git commit-tree $LATEST_TREE_HASH -p $PARENT_COMMIT_HASH`. But that's probably not the way to go.

Comment: @ckruczek, thanks for your remarks. I'm just experimenting. Rewriting history locally is OK, it's rewriting pushed histories is a problem. I'm quite proficient with git. It seems that after all there's no way to specify a parent for a commit. Just for the info, it's possible with low level commands, for example, `git commit-tree $LATEST_TREE_HASH -p $PARENT_COMMIT_HASH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides [Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47555787/1256452), there's a direct way to do this with two plumbing commands:

```
tree=$(git write-tree) # write updated index to new tree
commit=$(git commit-tree -p $firstparent -p $secondparent -F /tmp/msgfile)
```

(where `/tmp/msgfile` contains the commit message; note that you can use `-m` to specify message text, or `-F -` to read the message from stdin, in which case you could `git log --pretty=%B $hash` to extract the original commit message and pipe that to `git commit-tree`).

Once you have the commit you can `git merge --ff-only` or `git reset --hard` to it, e.g.:

```
git merge --ff-only $commit
```

I wonder, though, just what you mean by:

> reverted one resolution

and in all cases the result is what is generally called an "evil merge": a merge whose result is not based on its inputs.  Whether such a merge is truly evil, or even just a bad idea, is a matter of opinion, but it's certainly hard to reproduce later, and seems to call for a good commit message.

Comment: thanks, by `reverted` one resolution I meant that I made changes to the one conflicting file that I resolved incorrectly. _a merge whose result is not based on its inputs_ - I guess that could be said about any merge that results in a conflict since how those conflicts are resolved is non deterministic.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - It *could* be said about any merge that resolves conflicts, but it isn't.  The difference, of course, is that there *is no default resolution* to a merge that conflicts, which means (1) automated processing in the future won't "think" it did the right thing when it didn't, and (2) manual intervention was unavoidable anyway.  While torek is right that it's a matter of opinion, my opinion has turned more and more against evil merges the more I've had to actually deal with them in real repos.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, thanks for your comment. Just to clarify, is there a method to know if a merge was done without conflict resolutions by simply looking at one commit? I just don't see a way to distinguish an "evil" merge from not "evil". If using `torek`'s definition of an evil merge as a merge whose result is not based on its inputs, then does it mean that all merges resulting in conflicts and requiring manual non-deterministic resolutions are evil?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - Neither I nor anyone I know of who uses the term "evil merge" use it to describe a resolved conflicting merge. You can't easily tell if a merge is evil by looking at it - and that would be true even if merges never conflict, and that's why evil merges can cause problems. (i.e. if git *marked* evil merges, so that commands like `log` and `rebase` could address them appropriately, they would cease to be evil.) If you want a test for evil merges: rerun the merge. If it completes without conflict and the result diffs from the original, the original is an evil merge.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - By the way, my approach with "evil merges" is entirely based on pragmatism; and taking that approach, the *true* evil is that any merge using an alternative merge strategy (unless the default would conflict) is evil, *and* if the default merge behavior ever changes in ways that alter non-conflicted merge results, that would suddenly render all existing merges evil.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, okay, I see, thanks. So basically you can tell if a merge is evil only if it was merged without conflicts, correct? As if someone run merge with `no-commit` and then introduced some changes despite the fact that merge had no conflicts. And then execute `git merge --continue`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger (and AngularInDepth though comments only "@" one at a time, and aren't really the place for discussion) I haven't had a lot of chance to practice this idea, but I think the best way to deal with problematic merges is—or is at least "is likely to be"—to add a commit just before or just after the merge that addresses what would otherwise be the "evil part".

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you're trying to do, but two things:

First, it may not be a good idea.  If a merge contains changes (relative to the default merge result), then those changes are somewhat hidden.  It can confuse certain git commands you might run in the future (in particular rebase won't be able to deal with the merge correctly), and it makes it harder for someone looking through history to see how the project evolved.

Second, if you're going to do it anyway, there's probably an easier way than what you're trying.  If the merge conflicted, you could've made the changes before committing the conflict resolution.  And if it *didn't* conflict, you could re-run the merge with the `--no-commit` option so that you could make your manual change and then commit it.

But if, for whatever combination of reasons, you have the completed merge and don't want to re-run the merge operation, so you do a soft reset and now you want to recreate the merge commit with your current content state:

First you'll need a clean working tree, so

```
git stash
```

Now you can start the process of creating the merge commit.  Use the `ours` strategy to avoid any actual merging of changes; this will just keep your content state as it is.  Use `--no-commit` so that you can reapply the changes from the stash.

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit branch
git stash pop
git add .
git commit
```

And now you have your evil merge as you wanted it, ready to mess up your history when you least expect it.